# Return updated object value from list of objects

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

Hi I have a list of objects i want to return the updated object if condition matches else the object.
below is the code i tried. IT does not work.
It simply returns me the matches found with update.
I want those values also which do not match key value from list without updation.
Can we do this?

```
var bindingData = dataSource.Where(x => filesFoundDictionary.Any(y => y.Key == x.FileName)).Select(x => { x.Select = true; return x; }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `Where` and put your condition within `Select` statement instead:

```
var bindingData = dataSource
    .Select(x =>
    {
        if(filesFoundDictionary.ContainsKey(s.FileName)) 
            x.Select = true;
        return x;
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: You can replace `filesFoundDictionary.Any(y => y.Key == x.FileName)` with `filesFoundDictionary.ContainsKey(s.FileName)` since that is more efficient. The first is O(n) whereas the dictionary method is always O(1).

Comment: @TimSchmelter You're totally right! Updated my answer. Thanks!